# Add to React state array from within return of hook function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, parent

I have a situation with a Parent and Child component in React. Many child components will be instantiated and I need the parent to keep track of the state of all of them so that when all of the children are in the "passed" state, a continue button will no longer be disabled.

Here is where I instantiate my parent state array and define the text for each step in a different array.

```
const [stepsArray, setStepsArray] = useState([]);

const steps = [
 "step1",
 "step2",
 "step3"
]
```

I am passing a function to the Child components that will be called on render with useEffect.

```
useEffect( () => {
    const passFailObject:IPassFailObject = {
        name: props.name,
        passed,
        failed
    }
    props.updateParentArray(passFailObject);
}, []);
```

Then the parent function is:

```
const getChildState = (object:IPassFailObject):void => {
     setSteps([...stepsArray, object]);
}
```

Here is where I instantiate the child components:

```
<ol>
    {steps.map( step => <li key={step}><PassFailStep updateParentArray={getChildState} name={step} /></li>)}
</ol>
```

It seems that every time the getChildState function is called to update the state array, it has not been updated. I am guessing this is because the parent component has not left its return call, but I'm not exactly sure.

I think I can get around this with useRef and just pushing to that reference array, but I was wondering if there is a better way to accomplish what I am doing.

Comment: Are `stepsArray` and `steps` different arrays?

Comment: @Siddharth Yes they are, I made an addition to make the difference more clear. steps is the initial array that contains the text of each step which will then be used by the child components to make each step in the list.

Comment: When does a child component get into a "Passed" state?